# Pandas - value_counts on multiple values in one cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has a column with multiple values, separated by a comma like this:

```
Country
Australia, Cuba, Argentina
Australia
United States, Canada, United Kingdom, Argentina
```

I would like to count each unique value, similar to value_counts, like this:

```
Australia: 2
Cuba: 1
Argentina: 2
United States: 1
```

My simplest method is shown below, but I suspect that this can be done more efficiently and neatly.

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(pd.DataFrame(data['Country'].str.split(',', expand=True)).values.ravel())
```

Cheers

Comment: It's borderline abusing string datatype to store multiple comma-separated values in one string cell.. SQL experts would object, you can't parallelize such calculations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can using `get_dummies`

```
df.Country.str.get_dummies(sep=', ').sum()
Out[354]: 
Argentina         2
Australia         2
Canada            1
Cuba              1
United Kingdom    1
United States     1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to `split` and then use `value_counts`

```
pd.Series(df.Country.str.split(', ').sum()).value_counts()

Argentina         2
Australia         2
United Kingdom    1
Canada            1
Cuba              1
United States     1
dtype: int64
```